# Can we exploit the unique totient property of primes for a solution to Goldbach's Conjecture (strong)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, goldbachs-conjecture

The following setup takes advantage of the fact that the totient of every prime p is p-1:

1. Use an “All or nothing” approach in that: $$4\leq 2n=p+q\quad p,q\in\mathbb{P}\iff\forall 2n\geq 4, 2n=r+t\quad r,t\in\mathbb{P}$$
2. Use the totient-quotient value (see below) as a multiplicative identity (Quotient is equal to 1 iff both a and b are prime (non-trivial sum), and not equal to 1 iff both a and b are not prime (trivial sum)).
3. Plot even numbers greater than or equal to 4 with even numbers along the y-axis and sum pairs (not necessarily prime) along the x-axis. The resulting picture is that of an ever-ascending staircase, bridge or chain with each step, section or link, extending further than the last (The number of trivial and non-trivial sums increase as the even numbers increase).
4. Only the quotients that are equal to 1 (non-trivial sums) when multiplied by each “stair step” (the even numbers along the y-axis) fall on that “stair step”, whereas all trivial sums either fall short or surpass it (This is because the totient-quotient value for trivial sums is less or greater than 1). You see, it’s as if the prime sums—the non-trivial sums—are supporting the even numbers as though they provide their structural integrity, not unlike how piers, or supporting columns, keep physical bridges from collapsing under their own weight.
5. Substituting the number 1 with this “re-phrasing” of 1 as a multiplicative identity, in calculating the double factorial of even numbers from some 2n down to 4, e.g., $$(64\times 1)\times(62\times 1)\times(60\times 1)\times\cdots\times (4\times 1) = 64!!$$, we have a contradiction on our hands. If for some even number 2n, there exists no totient-quotient equal to 1, or no non-trivial sum, since, in the case above, 64!! would be less or greater than the actual value of 64!!, which is to say there would be two distinct products for a given set of prime factors, which contradicts the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Totient-quotient function: $$\frac{\phi(q)}{(2(n-1)-\phi(p))} =\begin{cases} 1\quad p,q\in\mathbb{P}\\m\neq{1}\quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases} \\2\leq p\leq q,4\leq n, p+q=n$$

Comment: Why is the claim in 1. true?

Comment: @Wojowu Proposition 1 is a result of proposition 4 and 5 and the totient function defined. If we were to start at 4 and work our way up to some 2n finding at least one non-trivial sum for each even number only to eventually find an even number with no non-trivial sum, then there would not have existed a non-trivial sum for the preceding even number, and so on, down to 4. The idea is that, primarily, it's not that each individual even number possibly has at least one prime sum, but that prime sums are an inherent property of, that is to say, exist for even numbers as they stand as a collective.

Comment: please work on your MathJax.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee Really? Are you trolling me?

Comment: It's standard precedure on this sight to use MathJax, and show work etc.

Comment: Show work... OK, what am I showing, then? Like, what doesn't make sense. Like, why is everyone so sensitive when it comes to something so frivolous as notation. What's the point of encoding ideas in fancy script if no-one wants to take the trouble to understand the problem in simple terms? It's like you know that I'm asking for a cup of water, I point to it, I draw it on paper, but noooo, I forget that I'm in France or Germany, so my pronunciation must be unnecessarily unflinchingly precise.

Comment: if you ever want to publish work via a journal, you'll Almost certainly have ro encode it in such a manner. There are statements of Goldbach in terms of totient function values already, what makes yours exciting ?

Comment: Also it keeps everything roughly standard. Your less than or equals look like implies drawn backwards. * can mean any binary operator in some places. etc.  your descriptions are all able to be able to be put in picture or formula form. oh and even your sloppy math is a notation.

Comment: I can take sloppy as long as it's right. Oh my goodness. It's called context clues. I stated double factorial, what else could '*' possibly mean? You know it's multiplication and you know I mean less than or equal and not a conditional operator. But, yes, point taken. I'll put everything in MathJax (boooring). God forbid there be a GUI for inserting proper notation on a scientific-minded message board.

Comment: Sincerely, though, thx for not downvoting this post.

Comment: @Roddy MacPhee I missed your question: "There are statements of Goldbach in terms of totient function values already, what makes yours exciting ?" I am using this particular totient function as a way of writing '1' as it's used as a multiplicative identity. The function is a test that fails when no non-trivial sum exists as a possible solution for some 2n (n > 1). In the double factorial example, replace the right multiplicand in each set of parentheses ('1') with this totient function. The idea is that if the totient test were to fail for some 2n, then the factorial would break down.